# Firebase runTransactionBlock() deletes node

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, firebase

I am using Firebase SDK (2.4.2) for iOS. The following code is part of the `didSelectPost()` function used in `SLComposeServiceViewController` object. It's very important to indicate that this behavior is not the same when used in a regular `UIViewController` (weird I know).

Assuming the following basic code:

```
    override func presentationAnimationDidFinish() {
        // Retrieving content and identifying type here
    }

    override func didSelectPost() {
        self.myRootRef.runTransactionBlock({
            (currentData:FMutableData!) in
                currentData.value = "test"

                // Finalizing the transaction
                return FTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
            }
        )

        self.extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems([], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

When the transaction is complete `node_value` disappears completely from Firebase. The value is not set and the node is deleted. This is a very weird and unexpected behavior!

On the other hand, the following code works as expected.

```
    override func didSelectPost() {
        self.myRootRef.setValue("test", withCompletionBlock: {
            (error:NSError?, ref:Firebase!) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Data could not be saved.")
            } else {
                print("Data saved successfully!")
            }
        })

        self.extensionContext!.completeRequestReturningItems([], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

This problem did not exist a couple of days ago, last I ran the code above. Any insights as to what the problem is?

Comment: Let me know if my answered work for you. If so please mark it as accepted. It's good to keep the unanswered queue clear.

Comment: @DavidEast I did not get the time to test the answer yet. I will most likely do so this weekend, after that I will confirm the answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `nil` to a path in a Firebase database, it will do the same as a `.removeValue()`.

**When running a transaction you should check for `nil`.** Since transactions can be called with `nil` if no default value was written.

```
myRootRef.runTransactionBlock({
    (currentData:FMutableData!) in
    var value = currentData.value as? Int
    if value == nil { 
        value = 0
    }
    currentData.value = value! + 1
    return FTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
})
```

Read the [Firebase Docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions) for more information.

Comment: this did not solve the problem. I believe the scenario I'm working with has more variables than the question suggests. There is another app that is subscribed to change events of this node. When a change happens it grabs the data and clears the content. Nevertheless, this was never an issue until recently.